# improving prediction in sklearn

Tags: nlp, scikit-learn, prediction

I am looking for some guidance. I am new to NLP. I can find my way round python ok and got some feature extractors coded. What I want to do is being able to predict emotion type such as happy, sad etc using sklearn. To this end I created a feature extractor that extracts several features like starting POS, ending POS, number of punctuations, number of WH__ words etc. It creates an array of these features and I am trying to find a way to use this data for supervised learning. I already went over all the 800+ sentenses and have targets to answer the sentences. Then I am giving the first 750 arrays and the answer array to sklearn and then try to predict on the last 50. sklearn predicts but the predictions are really poor.

Sure it is my problem than the sklearn. I am looking for some guidance to help me through in terms of perhaps right feature suggestions, suggestions re: normalizing the data, and in general any guidance really. I will give examples below.

Text file contains one sentence per line, feature extractor loads each sentence and gives out a feature list as an array.
At this point data looks like

features array of arrays :

```
    setx=[[1, 0, 5, 12, 5, 13, .... -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 17, 11, 0],..... many more arrays like this]
```

targets array:
        sety=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..... 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Then I am using :

```
    clf=svm.SVC(gamma=0.001,C=10)
    clf.fit(setx,sety)
```

The tstx and tsty below are the last 50 of the total feature arrays and targets array

```
    count=0
    for n in tstx:
            print clf.predict(n),',',tsty[count]
            count=count+1
            print "-----"
```

Any suggestions on improving the predictions! I am pretty sure I am missing holes the size of Texas somewhere :-)

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Well, machine learning is not a craft, but really an art. I would suggest reading what other people did and get inspiration from their ideas. This is not really a programming question, so it's rather off-topic here at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading up on the comments for the answer by @ The Coding Monk, this might not be a complete solution, but it might work for sentiment analysis.

1. Instead of explicitly extracting features, try using sklearn's `TfIdfVectorizer`. TfIdfVectorizer will pick up words from your sentences based in the TF-IDF score
2. Since you already have a list of classified sentences i.e. sentences with a sentiment value from 0-6, you can easily train a classifier in conjuntion with TfIdfVectorizer
3. You can combine the two steps by using `sklearn Pipeline`

Here's how it will look

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model.logistic import LogisticRegression

pipeline=Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',sublinear_tf=True)),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
    ])

from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
parameters={}#for simplicity, keep this blank for now

gridSearchClassifier = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=3, verbose=1, scoring='accuracy')
```

once we have the pipeline set up, we can bring in our training data

```
import pandas as pd
traindf = pd.read_csv('path to your data')
# Create learning matrix
X, y = traindf['sentenceColumn'], traindf['sentimentColumn'].as_matrix()
# Split into Training and Validation Sets

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
Xtrain, Xvalidate, ytrain, yValidate = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7)
```

and finally, for training all you have to do is

```
gridSearchClassifier.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

now you can evaluate your performance on the validation set

```
# Evaluate performance of gridSearchClassifier on Validation Set
    predictions = gridSearchClassifier.predict(Xvalidate)
    print ('Accuracy:', accuracy_score(yValidate, predictions))
    print ('Confusion Matrix:', confusion_matrix(yValidate, predictions))
    print ('Classification Report:', classification_report(yValidate, predictions))
```

if you are satisfied, then bring in your last 50 sentences as your Test Set

```
testdf = pd.read_csv("path to test data") 
# Predict Sentiment on Test Set
predictions=gridSearchClassifier.predict(testdf['sentenceColumn'])
# Create new column in Test dataframe
testdf['predictedSentiment'] = predictions
# Save the dataframe with the new column
testdf.to_csv("result.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Hi AbtPst, thanks for the answer. I am trying this and also reading the scikit books now. Thanks again for the guidance. I will update once I get further out.

Comment: glad to help :) all the best

Answer (score 3):

The performance of your system can depend on a variety of different factors but the features you use and the number of classes ("targets") you're trying to predict play a fundamental role. Some questions you should ask yourself are:

- **How many classes do you have?** Learning to differentiate among 5 different classes is easier than learning 50, if the number of classes increases you probably need more examples.
- **Is the class distribution balanced?** In general, the best thing would be to have an equal amount of examples for each class (sad, happy, etc...) with no class being over- or under-represented.

Despite this, I believe your problem is in the features. The ones you listed in the answer do not seem to be very useful for sentiment analysis. The starting POS of a sentence is not indicative as to which feeling is expressed in the sentence, nor is, I would say, the number of Wh- words or the number of punctuation.
I can't really give you a specific answer, but I suggest you read something about useful features for sentiment analysis, the field is vast and there are several approaches you can take. A simple search of Google Scholar will find you lots of material to take inspiration from. As an example, you could start by taking a look at [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/), which is a sentiment annotated version of WordNet, and try to use information contained in it as features for your model.

**EDIT**
The only features that I think could be useful for sentiment prediction are the # of positive and negative words, but I may be mistaken since I'm not an expert in the field. The others, like starting POS, ending POS, number of Wh- words may be useful for the interrogative vs declarative prediction. If you're doing nothing wrong in your code and your results are not good, then you have to experiment with more/different features. Also, don't use all the features for each task: you should design a specific feature set for each thing you are trying to predict, as feature that are useful for sentiment 
analysis may not be useful for other predictions and viceversa, and they could be actually confusing for the classifier. There are lots of methods to see if a feature has predictive value for a target, for example see [this](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~mhall/thesis.pdf), but I never used them so I can't give a practical feedback on that. Maybe you should look if there is something already implemented in sklearn that you can use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Classification-wise I am only looking for a handful of classes - emotion type is 6 classes, other things like emotion strength is 4, emotion mode is just positive vs neg etc. So not  alot of classes. Comment re: selected features is helpful. I have extracted overall 126 features. some of the classes are more balanced than others- I am trying to predict several different classes - not at the same time though. At any time I am using one target and one prediction class. So from your view, does it sound like the rest is on the right track, except choosing right features?

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understood everything you said, but yes I believe the problem is in the features. What are these 126 features you are using besides the ones you listed in the question? Those you provided are not really descriptive of sentiment in a sentence.

Comment: Hi, I extracted number of positive words, number of negative words, patterns of consonants and vowels, sentence length, number of caps, number of words duplicated/repeated, type and numbers of punctuations, all POS, number of noun phrases, POS positions. I have all possible POS from penn tree and created a list with them. Now for each type of POS from this list, if this POS exists in the given sentence, I put the list index of this POS else -1. Also extracted the beginning and ending POS, number of WH words. I can give the entire script here - just don't want to annoy people. cont..

Comment: I am trying to predict multiple things, not all at the same time. For eg, I want to predict the type of sentence, interrogative vs declarative vs ... I have these 800 or so sentences that I already scored as one or other type of sentences, having one or other type of emotion, certain level of strength etc. So I am using the features and one target at a time. 

If the features I extracted don't make sense I will appreciate any suggestions in the right direction.

Comment: cont ... I wonder if there is a way to load each feature along with the chosen target and then plot it to see if this feature actually has any predictive value for that particular target?

Thanks &
Have a good weekend

Comment: Thanks. I am using a ndarray of features as (725, 2) and targets(725,) to test a couple of features at a time. 
        scaler=ppx.StandardScaler().fit(features)
        xtx=scaler.transform(features)
        cols=['red'...]
        for i in xrange(len(cols)):
            xs=xtx[:,0][ty==i]
            ys=xtx[:,1][ty==i]
            plt.scatter(xs,ys,c=cols[i])
        plt.legend(sentx)
        plt.xlabel('feature 1')
        plt.ylabel('feature 2')
        plt.show()

I am trying to understand it but if you have any suggestions I'll greatly appreciate. I am reading the link you sent. Tx

Comment: I don't really use python so I can't check you code. Btw, the link I sent is just an example I happened to find, it's a bit old, I believe it is still valid but there are a lot of other resources. You need to look for "feature selection".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I am  reading up that and scipy numpy, and scikit. I will try and pick a small set of features at a time and see what i get.